# cachegrind only collects Ir event

Tags: valgrind, cachegrind

I've run `valgrind --tool=cachegrind my_program`, and am inspecting the output with `cg_annotate`. However, I see

```
Invocation:       /nix/store/790436pvihffwg2y1i8f29q2zw932c7j-valgrind-3.21.0/bin/cg_annotate cachegrind.out.20670
Command:          my_program
Events recorded:  Ir
Events shown:     Ir
Event sort order: Ir
Threshold:        0.1%
Annotation:       on
```

so apparently only `Ir` was collected, but I'm interested in some of the other outputs, like D2mr. How can I cause those to be collected, and/or why aren't they collected by default.

Note: I'm running in linux inside WSL - maybe some features are disabled inside WSL?

Comment: Have you read the documentation by any chance? My guess is no. I’ll give you a hint though. The default for cache simulation changed in Valgrind 3.22.